# Adding WPF user control in a window/grid the QT way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've a user control `UCConveyorBelt`. My main window simply has a grid. I want the user control to be placed in the grid. There are two ways I know:

1. Using the code `gridMain.Children.Add(new UCConveyorBelt());` it can be added dynamically. The problem is that I can't use the Design view to manipulate the user control.
2. Using XAML directly. A tag can be added named `UCConveyorBelt`. But I don't want to touch XAML directly as this will be error prone and I don't feel it is the easy way to manipulate UI.

<strike>The problem of both approaches is that I can't use the Design view to manipulate the user control. I want to add the `UserControl` using the Design view.</strike>

This can be done in latest version of Qt Creator (well, not for WPF). In Qt Creator, a `QWidget` can be subclassed and a custom widget can be written. A `QWidget` can be added in the UI. Then, the UI's `QWidget` can be promoted to the subclassed widget. This way, I can manipulate (resize, etc) the custom widget from the Design view and I can check relative positions of the custom widgets w.r.t. other widgets. Is it possible to do something similar in WPF?

I'm using VS 2008.

Comment: If you add using XAML, you should be able to use the design view in Visual Studio -- why can't you use the design view?  Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: @ErenErsonmez: i'm very sorry. why i don't want to use XAML directly is mentioned separately. you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to manipulate a usercontrol using the design view (drag & drop into the design view).
Just make sure you have compiled the assembly that contains your usercontrol. Then your control should appear in the "Toolbox" window of Visual Studio.
If it's not the case, you can right-click on the toolbox window -> Choose Items -> then select your assembly.

Tested with VS 2010 / Silverlight 4. As far as I can remember, this is the same with 2008 and WPF.